# Random walks (eigenvalue representation) how to prove matrix M (of transition probabilities) satisfies $M^{T}\pi=1.\pi.$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk

This is a question for someone familiar with random walks and its connection to eigenvalues.

So we have $M=D\cdot{A_G}$ in which $A_G$ is the adjacency matrix and $D$ is the diagonal, where $(D)_{ii}=1/d(i).$

In what I am reading, I have written here that "$M^{T}\pi=1.\pi$ expresses the fact that $\pi$ is the stationary distribution."

I am unsure on how to prove that $M^T$ satisifies this eigenvalue equation? Is it basic knowledge from matrices? $\pi$ is left eigenvalue and $1$ is right eigenvalue. $M^T$ is simply $M$ after time $T$ for our random walk.

Here is what I am reading http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/erdos.pdf.

See page 3 and 4 for intro definitions.

See page 14 for where my problem has arose, it is where section 3 starts.

Thank you for any help you can offer, please let me know if you require more info.

Comment: That's not what $M^T$ means: it's just the transpose! This is essentially the definition of a left-eigenvector.

Comment: Oh silly me! Do you know why $M^T$ has left eigenvalue $\pi$ and right eigenavalue $1$? I understand that $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of a random walk, and does the $1$ have something to do that each time step is $1$ step?

Comment: Oh silly me! Do you know why $M^T$ has left eigenvalue $\pi$ and right eigenavalue $1$? I understand that $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of a random walk (to do with mixing time of a random walk - eventually probability of being at each vertex stays the same after so many steps in the random walk), and does the $1$ have something to do that each time step is $1$ step of the random walk?

Comment: The probability distribution after one iteration is $M^T$ times the prior probability distribution, so the stationary distribution will satisfy $M^T \pi = \pi$ (that is the definition of stationary: it doesn't move).  The statement $M\vec1 = \vec1$ is just a concise way to say that every row of $M$ adds up to $1$.  Also, these are left and right eigen**vectors**, not eigenvalues.  (There's no difference between a left- and right-eigenvalue.)